# How many partitions should we create if there are around 100 millions rows

Tags: mysql, partition

I have a 16 core , 12 GB ram, a SSD 500 MB/s
I have 1 millions rows in my "Pages" table

The pages contains 1 unique key that are HostID ( int ) and Page( varchar )

I use partitioning by key 
and have created briefly about 100 partitions

But i'm not sure that how many partitions that i should create for best performance.

briefly about 70 GB of data
I use primary key to search :

```
    select * from table where HostID = 1 AND Page = 'asdasd'
```

Comment: And you created all of those partitions on the same physical disk?

Comment: How big is one record (or how big is the whole table in GB)? Are you searching by HostID or by Page? What is the primary key of the table?

Comment: @N.B: yes .  70 GB of data , 200 GB of space

Comment: That defeats purpose of partitions.. partitions are there to help scale writes (and reads to some point). If you use the exact same hard drive - well, it makes no sense. The point of the partition is so that the data can reside at different locations, so that your MySQL doesn't become disk IO bound. To answer your question - the more partitions you create on that same SSD, the more complex your app will get with NO speed benefit. Use more hard drives.

Comment: @N.B - Its not true that there will be no benefit at all if its all on the same disk. The concept of "partition pruning" can speed up queries dramatically. Smaller per-partition indexes will have another benefit as well. He'll be better off with multiple disks but partitioning is about more than just that.

Comment: @bot403 - To scale writes, you use partitioning. To scale reads, you use distribution master with slaves. It's how things are done, to put it simply (we could all write books about pros and cons). To keep things **simple**, without much discussion if you get 1% or X% performance - performance gain when partitioning on the same disk is negligible. Even SSD is IO bound, even if the queries are faster slightly - in the long run it won't matter. To gain the best use of partition, it's the best to use different physical location for the partition storage.

Comment: You could also divide to multiple tables. As you don't do multi-hostID searches you could split this to 100 tables with eg. according to hostID%100 ( 1, 101, 201 in first table, 2, 102, 202 to second etc ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the following answer which demonstrates how best to use clustered primary keys with the innodb engine of interest.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419499/mysql-nosql-help-me-to-choose-the-right-one-on-a/4421601#4421601

Hope this helps :)